# Is it possible to use matlab tables in mex code?

Tags: matlab, mex

I would like to manipulate a matlab table (http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html) inside mex code. Is that possible?

For example to manipulate an array in mex code one would call:

```
mxArray * matlabArray = prhs[0] ;// if matlabArray was the first argument to the mex function;
```

Can one do something like

```
mxTable * matlabTable  = prhs[0] ; //mxTable does not actually exist... but I would like it to:)
```

and pass a table as the first argument?

Comment: What happens if you do `mxArray * matlabArray = prhs[0] ` and prhs[0] is a table? Does it throw errors or can you view the values?

Comment: Nothing happens. In the VC++ debugger, you can inspect matlabArray, (as a float point for example) but it does not resemble what I passed. you can also take the underlying data (through mxGetPr(matlabArray) and assign it to a double vector, and then move through this vector (idx++) but there are 0s in the first few bytes (considered as 64 bit doubles)... I mean prhs[0] is just a pointer so why should it throw an error anyway?  I passed this table: "table([-1,3.14,2.78]', categorical({'a', 'b', 'c'})'"

Comment: What do you want to do with table? You probably have to call MATLAB functions using mexCallMATLAB and pass the table mxArray as input to do the processing in MATLAB.

Comment: @Navan, thanks for bringing my attention to mexCallMATLAB. The point of the question is to find out whether the mex library provides any C functionality to manipulating the table, for example innerjoins or aggregations or anything else you might want to do with a table. I don't have a specific use case...

Comment: I do not think there are any table specific mex library functions.

Answer (score 2):

`prhs` is an array of `mxArray` pointers, so your first line of code is correct.

Use `mxIsClass` (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxisclass.html) to determine if the input array is of type `table`:

```
if (mxIsClass(prhs[0],"table") { ... }
```

To access properties of the table, use the `mxGetProperty` (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetproperty.html) function:

```
mxArray* data = mxGetProperty(prhs[0],0,"ColumnName");
```

This is equivalent to the MATLAB command `table.ColumnName`. `data` should then by a normal double matrix. Unfortunately, this syntax creates a copy of the data. There are no documented ways of accessing data inside of (non-standard) objects without making copies. For undocumented ways, see: http://www.advanpix.com/2013/07/19/undocumented-mex-api/

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to access a Matlab table in a mex function based upon the following:

1. You can do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on the Matlab C/C++, Fortran and Python API Reference for `table` and come up with only references to tables in the text. I would take this as evidence that there is no mxTable type provided.
2. The `table` type in Matlab is implemented as a Matlab class. You can actually see all of the source code for tables by simply typing `edit table` in the command window. This is not true for numeric arrays or cell arrays.

This doesn't appear to be an omission in mex support though since the main [advantage of tables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/advantages-of-using-tables.html) is that they organize data well. If you have computational requirements that would push you towards writing a mex function, you'll probably be working with numeric arrays in Matlab already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution to work around the limitation of MATLAB table access by using a MATLAB specific function for extracting the data you need, like this:

```
function res = extract_table_data(tbl, column)
    res = tbl.(column);
end
```

Inside C mex code you can define `tbl_get_column` like:

```
static mxArray* tbl_get_column(const mxArray* tbl, const char* column_name)
{
    mxArray* column_arg = mxCreateString(column_name);

    mxArray* args[] = { (mxArray*)tbl,  column_arg };
    mxArray* result = 0;

    mexCallMATLAB(1, &result, 2, args, "extract_table_data");

    mxDestroyArray(column_arg);

    return result;
}
```

Inside your `mexFunction` you can access the data as follows:

```
    mxArray* time_arr = tbl_get_column(prhs[0], "Time");
```

Tested with MATLAB R2021b